# Looping through an multidimensional array until condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, multidimensional-array

I'm fetching an array of objects at an interval of one second from an external API and mapping the array of objects in react native. These mapped objects are : `CurrencyPair`, `BuyingPrice` and `sellingPrice`. An example of the mapped objects is

```
[
  "USD_CHF",
  "0.90512",
  "0.90497",
]
```

which is a one dimensional array and  as represented above respectively.

Secondly, the user is required to select a currency pair of their choice and input a buying price and a message, such that when the `BuyingPrice` of the `selectedcurrencypair`(fetched from the api) is equal to the `BuyingPrice` of the `SelectedCurrencyPair` selected by the user, an alert is triggered with the message with it. I have placed the user input data as a multidimensional array and tried looping as i check when the condition is true, but it seems the if statement in the loop is not being checked. Below is my code:

```
// Mapping array of objects 

const result = data.prices.map(value =>
  [value.instrument, value.closeoutAsk, value.closeoutBid]
);
checkCondition(...result);
```

```
//function containing the comparison condition

function checkCondition({ BuyThreshold, SMSMessage }) {
  // initialize your stack
  const myStack=[];
  // create a new row
  const row = [];
  const SelectedCurrencyPair =
    currency.data.prices[clickedindex].instrument;

  row.push(SelectedCurrencyPair);
  row.push(BuyThreshold);
  row.push(SMSMessage);
  // insert the row

  myStack.push(row);

  for (let i = 0; i < myStack.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {

      if (result[j][0] === myStack[i][0]){
        if (result[j][1] >=  myStack[i][1])  {

          Alert.alert(myStack[i][0],"Target Price has hit : " + myStack[i][1]);
        } else {
          console.log("Price not reached");
        }
      } else{
        console.log("Wrong currency pair");
      }
    }
  }
}
checkCondition({ SelectedCurrencyPair, BuyThreshold, SMSMessage});
```

```
<Modal
  visible={modalopen}
  transparent={true}
  animationType={"fade"}
>
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000aa'}}>
    <View style={{margin: 10, backgroundColor: '#ffffff', padding: 30, flex: 1, borderRadius: 10}}>

      <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
        Create Alert On: 
      </Text>          
      <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
        <>
          {currency.data.prices[clickedindex].instrument}
        </>
      </Text>
  
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent:"center", marginTop: 20 }}>
        <View style={styles.inputWrap}>

          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInputStyle}
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={ BuyThreshold}
            onChangeText = {(BuyThreshold) => setBuyThreshhold(BuyThreshold)}
            placeholder="BuyPrice"
            placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
            numeric
            
            clearButtonMode='always'
            keyboardType='decimal-pad'  
          /> 
          <TextInput
            style={styles.messageStyle}
            value={SMSMessage}
            onChangeText = {(SMSMessage) => setSMSMessage(SMSMessage)}
            placeholder="Message"
            clearButtonMode='always'
            
            placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
          />

        </View>
      </View>  
    
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {
          checkCondition({BuyThreshold, SMSMessage});
          // navigation.navigate("MyAlerts");

          setModalOpen(false);
          showToastWithGravityAndOffset();
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>OK</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress ={() => setModalOpen(false)}>
            <Text>Close</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: need more info. I don't know why are you calling  `checkCondition({SelectedCurrencyPair,BuyThreshold, SMSMessage});` in the last line for instance.
Please put  your whole code that matters (instead of making us  make assumptions)

Comment: `checkCondition(...result)` contradicts the arguments signature of `checkCondition` which expects a single object. The last line of the last code block does a correct invocation, but here the properties are provided *"out of the blue"*.

Comment: @PeterSeliger How can i access the result in the `checkCondition` function

Comment: @iwaduarte Added code for context

Comment: @user23424 ... may you please pay respect to how to format code every time you edit any of the code blocks. Thanks in advance. If code can not be read easily, the amout of people willing to provide help does drop significantly.

Comment: Okay...thank you for that

Comment: again, what is this and where these variables: checkCondition({ SelectedCurrencyPair, BuyThreshold, SMSMessage});

Comment: @iwaduarte `BuyThreshold` and `SMSMessage` are values from the textinput

Comment: @PeterSeliger That was actually the issue. Thank you so much